# Drupal multisite on a shared hosting

Tags: multi-sites

Is there a way to install Drupal multisite feature (it needs access to http.conf and http.vhosts) on a Shared Hosting with shell access? It also needs to hosts projects with different databases.

I know there is a module named: Domain Access for share Drupal database with affiliated sites but this is not actual I want.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good answer for this, as it will vary host-to-host.

Sometimes, shared hosts use management tools that map domains to accounts to directories.  This makes it hard(er) to do the Apache [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias) settings.  I have worked with shared hosts that have let this happen.

Sometimes, hosts will map domains to user accounts and run Apache in FastCGI mode, which may complicate things.

You need to contact your host to see what is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest giving it a try first. Rather than worrying about httpd.conf access, you can just use inbuilt tools to do that.. 
If your host has cPanel, you ***can*** host a Drupal multisite without manual edits to httpd.conf file.

Just make use of Parked Domain thin in cPanel correctly. All you need to do is, pointing extra domains to the main domain.

http://drupal.org/node/1068894

This is an article I authored a long time ago, for Domain Access module docs but I think it was updated several times to include cPanel and Direct-Admin specific instructions. It's not very limited to Domain Access. Just follow the same instructions.

In brief, if you "park" a domain, that's similar to aliasing. You can point any domain to the main domain that you purchased your account for. But you will not be able to point to an `addon domain` which is a limitation  for shared hosting accounts.

Also, as you have shell access, you can symlink.

I don't want to mention any commercial names. But if you really need to know a shared host that allow this type of multisites, that host's name mention an animal name.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience I can say it would work with webfaction.com cloud (not shared) for around $20/month. I run D7 and D8 websites on it.

I also managed to build my own stack with apache and php-fpm as local user (yes, you have shell access and can compile whatever you like). Benefit is also you can add additional php modules like twig.so and uploadprogress.so. They  running a nginx as frontend server and will "connect" to your local running apache/nginx process.